# ¿Cómo junto líneas que están separadas en bloques delimitados por "--"?

Tags: awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo la siguiente serie y necesitaría que cada vez que esté '--' se imprima hasta el siguiente '--' todo el contenido separado por comas

```
    true
    1
    2
    3
--
    true
    1
    2
    3
--
    true
    1
    2
--
    false
    1
    2
    3
--
    true
    1
    2
    3
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
true,1,2,3
true,1,2,3
true,1,2
false,1,2,3
true,1,2,3
```

Estaba usando el siguiente comando, pero en algunos casos, entre '--' hay menos filas

```
awk 'NR%4{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1'
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define el separador de bloques como "--" en lugar del salto de línea: `RS="--"` (por defecto, `RS="\n"`). De esta manera, cada registro/bloque será un conjunto de líneas en lugar de una sola y cada campo será una línea (por defecto cada campo es una "palabra").

De este modo, simplemente debes iterar sobre los campos e imprimirlos uno tras otro:

```
$ awk -v RS="--" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s%s",$i, i<NF ? "," : "\n")}' fichero
true,1,2,3
true,1,2,3
true,1,2
false,1,2,3
true,1,2,3
```

La lógica para imprimir es:

- "," si es un registro cualquiera
- salto de línea si es el último

Comment: genial! me sirve.